# How do you master adpositions, besides memorisation?

Tags: learning-methods, adpositions

`Summary of Question:` Many popular books only  suggest memorisation  (useless for many) and do not explain adpositions and their uses. Beyond memorisation, how else can a language learner  master the acquisition of adpositions? Though adpositions are Functional Morphemes, the failure of memorisation forces me to pursue more effective methods, such as Googling 'semantics of [insert language here] prepositions' and trying to understand the resulting linguistics papers.

`Optional Supplement:` The omittable following is published in 2 sources identically:
<sub>[p 2](http://vialjournal.webs.uvigo.es/pdf/Vial-2011-Article7.pdf), *Applying  Cognitive  Linguistics  to  Learning  the  Semantics  of  English 
to, for 
and
 at: 
An Experimental Investigation*, also by [Prof Andrea Tyler](http://faculty.georgetown.edu/tyleran/), C Mueller, V Ho.

[pp 130-131](https://books.google.ca/books?id=jOiSAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA130&ots=3cUc49Eme1&dq=%22semantics%20of%20prepositions%22%20L2&pg=PA130#v=onepage&q=%22semantics%20of%20prepositions%22%20L2&f=false), *[Cognitive Linguistics and Second Language Learning: Theoretical Basics and Experimental Evidence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415802504)*.</sub>

> Language  teachers  and  researchers  have  long  recognized  that  the  acquisition
>   of  prepositions  poses  major  challenges  for  second  language  learners  (e.g.,  Celce-Murcia  and  Larsen-Freeman,  1999).
>   One  reason  for  this  is  that  the  semantics  of  prepositions are    notoriously difficult to characterize. [...]  Additionally, prepositions tend to develop a complex 
>   set  of  extended  meanings,  for  instance,  *over* 
>   has  developed  at  least  16  meanings,  many of which do not appear to be systematically related. Although linguists have 
>   long been aware that prepositions develop complex polysemy networks, the meaning networks  surrounding  spatial  markers  (and  the  systematic  processes  of  meaning  extension  from  which  they  result)  have  only  become  the  foci  of  linguistic  inquiry
>   in  the  last  20  years.  Even  the  best  descriptive  grammars  and  dictionaries  present
>   the multiple meanings of spatial language as largely arbitrary. Traditional accounts 
>   have represented the semantics of English prepositions as arbitrary (Bloomfield, 1933; Frank,  1972;  Chomsky,  1995).  Consequently,  pedagogical  treatments  have  often  suggested memorization as the best strategy. Studies show that accurate use of spatial 
>   language is one of the last elements learned and many highly proficient L2 speakers 
>   never  attain  native  speaker-like  use  (e.g.,
>     Lam,  2009).  Indeed,  Lam  found  that  L2  Spanish learners made virtually no gains in their mastery of the prepositions 
>   *por*
>    and 
>   *para*
>    over the course of four years of college Spanish.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trained linguistically, so I need a clarification: You're asking how to learn the structure behind a language's use of prepositions, without using memorization, which is often the only strategy presented in learning materials? Am I close to understanding, or not? :)

Comment: @Numeri No need to be sorry; I am also not trained in linguistics! Yes, you are close, if not exactly correct! Yes: I am asking about how to learn prepositions without using memorisation `which is often the only strategy presented in learning materials`, but which (as the quote above states) fails for many language learners. I used the term 'adpositions' because it covers both prepositions and postpositions.

Comment: Thanks! It's a very interesting question. I'm interested to see the suggestions, because there's often a partial, but not complete overlap in *adpositions'* (new word!) meanings between languages that makes it hard for me to know which to use.

Comment: @Numeri You are welcome! Was my writing unclear though (sometimes I overcomplicate)? Please feel free to clarify and edit my post if it is unclear.

Comment: Potential related question: "Is memorisation useless for many?"

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to actively memorize rules to learn how to use adpositions (prepositions / postpositions); but a lot of time is needed to acquire the patterns.  I think a combination of passive and active methods is most useful:

**1. Input**

Get lots of input, by reading a lot and listening a lot.  If you're trying to learn the rules of which adposition to use through a grammar or exercise book, you're understanding of the rules will not be deep - it will be technical, and you'll have difficulty seeing the subtleties that exist (grammar books often paint the differences between forms in black and white, when they are often quite gray).  When you get lots of input, you'll see adpositions used properly, and you'll learn a lot of the patterns subconsciously.

**2. Notice patterns actively**

If you're getting lots of input, try to notice the patterns you see regarding the adpositions.  The patterns you notice yourself are often better learned than the patterns / rules explained in grammar books.  When you do this, remmeber that the patterns are not strict rules, and that there are often very subtle differences.

**3. Get Feedback**

Try to get feedback regarding your usage of various adpositions.  Input is great, but some of the subtle differences can be very difficult to pick up on with input alone.  If you don't get any feedback, your mistakes will fossilize if you don't realize that you're making a mistake.  So you can try writing example sentences using various prepositions.  Try to use them in borderline cases where you're not exactly sure which one to use.  Ask a native speaker to give you feedback: which are definitely wrong, which sound unnatural or perhaps imply the wrong meaning, and which are correct.  If possible, ask a native speaker who is "linguistically literate" - someone who can explain why your mistakes are wrong.